# Evaluating Two Conditions in Pandas Dataframe with Separate Assignments

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, calculated-columns

After trying lots of different combinations and researching, I've come up with this solution but I'm still getting a ValueError. I need to make a "1" or "0" assignment based on an evaluation of a column comparison based on 2 results being above or below a threshold. For example, let's suppose my data looks like this:

df:

```
   avg   var1   
0  30     60   
1  40     50
2  45     20
3  50     10
4  50     74
```

df_final needs to look like this:

```
   avg   var1  condition 
0  30     60   1
1  40     50   1
2  45     20   0
3  50     10   0
4  50     74   1
```

I have tried this using "|" for the "or" operator and I've also tried using np.where with the condition below and get an answer but the answer is incorrect.

```
df['condition'] = df[(df.var1 > df.avg == 1) | (df.var1 < df.avg == 0)]
```

but get the ValueError.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thank you. I think I'm close but just off by a little.

Answer (score 2):

Just convert boolean mask (of the evaluated condition) to integer type:

```
df['condition'] = (df.var1 > df.avg).astype(int)
```

---

```
   avg  var1  condition
0   30    60          1
1   40    50          1
2   45    20          0
3   50    10          0
4   50    74          1
```

Comment: sorry, i'm not seeing how your code produces the answer. can you explain?

Comment: @user2100039, `df.var1 > df.avg` performs a vectorized comparison producing boolean result `True` or `False` for each row. `.astype(int)` will then cast boolean values to integer type